# More then 1 variable in $.getJSON

Tags: php, json

I'm getting a json string back from a php request. I do this like this:

```
        department = $("#department").val();
        hospital = $("#hospital").val();

        if (hospital = "Not entered") {
            hospital = "Meander";
        } else {
            hospital = $("#hospital").val();
        }

        console.log('changed'); 
        $.getJSON('functions/charts_hospital.php?hosp=' + hospital,
```

I also want to include department in this string after the `hosp=' + hospital` like this: `dept=' + department`. Is this possible and how do i do this?

Regards,

Bart

Comment: just add ` +"&dept="+department` to the end of the url.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: just add `&` to concatenate two variables to pass as GET params.

```
$.getJSON(
    'functions/charts_hospital.php?hosp='+hospital+'&dept='+department,
     function(data){}
);
```

P.S.: equality operator is `==`. In your first `if` you are setting `hospital` to the value `Not entered`.

Comment: Thanks! what i want is that if the value in listbox is "not entered" i want hospital to be "Meander". I cant get this to work indeed. Can you help?

Comment: `if (hospital == "Not entered") { hospital = "Meander";}` will do the job.

Comment: Another question: whats the difference between a get request via $.ajax etc. or a $.getJSON?

Comment: $.getJSON is equivalent to $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});

Comment: thanks! i'm using the $.getJSON as follow: `$.getJSON('functions/charts_hospital.php', {
     "hosp":hospital,
     "dept":department}` I found that a bit "cleaner". Thanks all!